# bootstrap, sidebar, accordion сворачивание меню

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap, accordion

Здравствуйте уважаемые знатоки и специалисты CSS, JS
Я пытаюсь понять как работает боковое меню типа *accordion*
Когда выбрано верхнее меню и затем выполняется переход по ссылке (она находится внутри) это верхнее меню не сворачивается, а продолжает быть раскрытым
Я использую в качестве учебного пособия [этот шаблон BootStrap](https://bootstrapmade.com/demo/NiceAdmin/)

Допустим я выбираю **Components** -> кликая по любой ссылке (Alerts, Accordion, Badges...) блок **Components** продолжает быть раскрытым

У себя я пытаюсь, используя шаблонизатор Jinja2, сделать подобное, но при переходе на новую страницу меню всегда закрывается

Подскажите пожалуйста куда надо смотреть и как это правильно сделать? Чтобы не сворачивалось